# OnClickListener Layout detection

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a custom button layout: Its a FrameLayout as a background with a normal Button in the center with an icon next to the text.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#F00">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonWithIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I had an `onClickListeners` on the Button and I realized, clicks on the background (=FrameLayout) weren't detected. Because of this I want an onClickListener that detects clicks on the FrameLayout and also on the Button, without having two Listeners, that do the same.

I tried giving the RelativeLayout an ID, but the layout couldn't be found (=null).

Maybe my button layout isn't optimal. But I need a fullwidth button with a icon next to the text, without any spaces between the icon and the text.

The Icons gets set like this

`button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.ic_icon, 0, 0,0);`

Thank you

Comment: If all you need is a button with no "space" in between the end of it, and the next view (your icon), then how about removing it with [setPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)): `button.setPadding(0,0,0,0);` If this didnt help, check also [the Layout params for Magins](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html), in the ViewHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add one `OnClickListener` to both views. That way, you only write your code once, and if you click either the `FrameLayout` or the `Button` that same code will run.

```
    final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Add Your OnClick Code Here

        }
    };

    framelayout.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    buttonWithIcon.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of your views that you want them to be clickable and remove all `clickListeners` of entire views.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout">

<FrameLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#F00">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonWithIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and add this clickListener to LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout linearlayout=(linearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
 linearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Add Your Code Here
            }
        });
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing - in this solution, clicks on the Button (Icon and Text) arent registered.

Comment: Thank for your input. I added your edited answer to my project, but still the clicks on the Button aren't registered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your Activity with a View Argument, and in your layout, set the onClick to your two views.

**Activity:**

```
public void myAction(View v){
// Do what you want
}
```

**Your Layout:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
    android:onClick="myAction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#F00">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonWithIcon"
        android:onClick="myAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Maybe adding in just the FrameLayout may dispatch the event in the button also, i can't test right now :)